# unable to get click event between the path link using collapse graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using collapse graph.It works fine. But I am unable to add click event to the path link. so when I click on the path link i want to call function.how to do any one can help me.

[visit http://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/6FkBd/17/][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what you want in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dechorgnata/CVc3c/2/)

in the CSS file, I added that to visualize when the cursor in on the link:

```
.link:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

and this code for the link:

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
  ...
  .on("click", clickOnPath );

function clickOnPath(d){
    alert("click on path to "+ d.target.name);
}
```

**Edited:**
In the declaration of the *clickOnPath* function, you can inject d by exemple and then test whatever you want to switch to another function.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dechorgnata/CVc3c/) is also updated

Comment: thanx for your response ..but i need to pass different -2 function on each path link..it is possible in that

Comment: i need one more help ..i am using collapse graph its working fine for me.now i am unable to load on click to pass new external JSON file in the graph so that i can reload the whole graph.i am not getting any idea how to do can you please any one help regarding this.

Comment: for this second problem, I think you'd rather ask  a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: please, could you validate my answer?